# How can I produce a reciprocal scale for d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to make a scatter plot with both linear and reciprocal scales on multiple x axes with d3. If I try to use the power scales as below I just get NaN when using the function.

```
var reciprocal = d3.scale.pow().exponent(-1)
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something? If this shouldn't work is it possible to produce custom scales?

Comment: I actually managed to implement one by generating a list of ticks I wanted for the reciprocal axis and using the linear scale to manually position them. [You can see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/essennsee/KSAbK/279/)

Comment: I'm still interested in a more elegant solution to this though, especially as I aim to add the ability to zoom and pan the plot.